# rpmbuild error file not found even though files are in the path

Tags: linux, build, redhat, rpm, rpmbuild

i did the following but gotten error when running rpmbuild

Files are there in path

Any help or hint are appreciated

Thanks

```
rpmbuild -vv --buildroot $PWD/root --target x86_64 -bb bin-show.spec
Building target platforms: x86_64
Building for target x86_64
Processing files: helloworld-1.0-1.x86_64
error: File not found: /nobackup/username/prod/packaging/redhat/bin-show/root/etc/testpackage.conf


RPM build errors:
    File not found: /nobackup/username/prod/packaging/redhat/bin-show/root/etc/testpackage.conf
```

where bin-show.spec

```
#
# Hello World Spec File
#
Summary: Hello world!
Name: helloworld
Version: 1.0
Release: 1
License: Proprietary
Group: Applications/Utilities

%description
This is my first RPM test package!

%files
/etc/testpackage.conf
```

and the files structure

```
pwd
/nobackup/username/prod/packaging/redhat/bin-show

find . -name \*

./bin-show.spec
./root
./root/etc
./root/etc/testpackage.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

The messages from `rpmbuild` can be obscure.  It is probably complaining

- *not* that your filesystem lacks the file,
- but *rather* that the corresponding pathname does not exist under the `BUILDROOT` directory.

It normally expects that your spec-file will construct a set of files and directories under `~/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT` which it will collect into a package.  You can override the location of the `BUILDROOT` directory (and appear to have done this).  But your package expects

```
/etc/testpackage.conf
```

and (allowing for the apparent location of the `BUILDROOT` directory) you have given it

```
/root/etc/testpackage.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

Thomas is nearly correct about the origin of the error.

However rpmbuild expect that the file is present in

```
%{buildroot}/%{_sysconfdir}/testpackage.conf
```

You should either create it in `%install` section:

```
%install
echo some content > %{buildroot}/%{_sysconfdir}/testpackage.conf
```

or provide as SourceX:

```
Source1:  testpackage.conf

%install
cp -a %{SOURCE1} %{buildroot}/%{_sysconfdir}/

%files
%{_sysconfdir}/testpackage.conf
```