# rpmbuild error file not found while installing MUNGE

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec, munge

I am following [Munge installation guide](https://github.com/dun/munge/wiki/Installation-Guide) I downloaded the tar.gz file but  i am unable to create three rpm binaries as mentioned in the tutorials because of this

```
sudo rpmbuild -tb --clean munge-0.5.12-11-g4699a9f.tar.gz 
error: File /home/user1/Downloads/munge-0.5.12.tar.xz: No such file or directory
```

In home/rpmbuild/SPEC/munge.spec is created. But I am not getting where to edit. I referred answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35279698/rpmbuild-error-file-not-found-even-though-files-are-in-the-path) by [Thomas Dickey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4518274/thomas-dickey) it says to override the location of BUILDROOT directory not sure how one does that and according to answer by [muschy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3489429/msuchy) we need to add %install so i did that as well

```
%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}
make install DESTDIR=%{buildroot}
touch %{buildroot}/%{_sysconfdir}/munge/munge.key
touch %{buildroot}/%{_localstatedir}/lib/munge/munge.seed
touch %{buildroot}/%{_localstatedir}/log/munge/munged.log
touch %{buildroot}/%{_localstatedir}/run/munge/munged.pid
rm -f %{buildroot}/%{_sysconfdir}/sysconfig/munge
rm -f %{buildroot}/%{_initddir}/munge
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Calling "rpmbuild -tb" is quite unusual and barely documented. So I **think** it does:

1. extract any `*.spec` from tar file into ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/
2. copy tar file to ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/
3. call `rpmbuild -ba ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/that_extracted.spec`

And because you spec contains:

```
Source0: munge-%{version}.tar.xz
```

Then rpmbuild is looking for `munge-0.5.12.tar.xz` but your tar file is actually named `munge-0.5.12-11-g4699a9f.tar.gz`